# Ecto select relations from preload

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a query that pulls in relations to use in a json api. If I exclude the select statement it works fine, however, when I include the select statement the relations do not show up. I need the select statement to include a subquery for an attribute. How do I specify the relations in the select so that they will show?

```
journal_entries = from entry in JournalEntry,
  select: %{
    entry: entry,
    id: entry.id,
    account_id: entry.account_id,
    archived_at: entry.archived_at,
    date: entry.date,
    deleted_at: entry.deleted_at,
    is_closing: entry.is_closing,
    is_confirmed: entry.is_confirmed,
    note: entry.note,
    amount: (fragment("(SELECT sum(amount) FROM journal_entry_lines WHERE kind = 0 and journal_entry_id = ?)", entry.id))
  },
  preload: [
    :journal_entry_lines,
    journal_entry_lines: :journal_entry,
    journal_entry_lines: :chart_account
  ],
  where: entry.account_id == ^user.account_id
    and is_nil(entry.deleted_at)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `select/3`, you cannot use `preload/3` in the same way. You are going to have to do it manually.

```
journal_entries = from entry in JournalEntry,
  # Make sure you join all of the tables you want data for.
  join: jel in assoc(entry, :journal_entry_lines,
  select: %{
    entry: entry,
    id: entry.id,
    account_id: entry.account_id,
    archived_at: entry.archived_at,
    date: entry.date,
    deleted_at: entry.deleted_at,
    is_closing: entry.is_closing,
    is_confirmed: entry.is_confirmed,
    note: entry.note,
    amount: (fragment("(SELECT sum(amount) FROM journal_entry_lines WHERE kind = 0 and journal_entry_id = ?)", entry.id)),
    # Specify a key for your relation, and set its value.
    journal_entry_lines: jel
  },
  where: entry.account_id == ^user.account_id
    and is_nil(entry.deleted_at)
```

Comment: There are many journal entry lines for each journal entry, how would I prevent duplication?

Comment: You don't really. When you call `preload/3` it does a separate query to load that data to prevent the duplication. You could go that route and do multiple queries.